# How to store multiline data in a variable in Karate framework

Tags: karate

```
 * def value =
    """
    'Karate is the only open-source tool to combine API test-automation, mocks, performance-testing and even UI automation into a single, unified framework.'
 '1. The syntax is language-neutral, and easy for even non-programmers. Assertions and HTML reports are built-in, and you can run tests in parallel for speed.'
 '2. There\'s also a cross-platform stand-alone executable for teams not comfortable with Java. You don\'t have to compile code.'
    """
```

- def value2 =  value

  - print value2

I am assigning the value (which is a multiline string) to value2 variable and printing value2.

Could you please suggest.

what I was expecting to print

```
'Karate is the only open-source tool to combine API test-automation, mocks, performance-testing and even UI automation into a single, unified framework.'
 '1. The syntax is language-neutral, and easy for even non-programmers. Assertions and HTML reports are built-in, and you can run tests in parallel for speed.'
 '2. There\'s also a cross-platform stand-alone executable for teams not comfortable with Java. You don\'t have to compile code.'
```

what its printing is

```
2. There's also a cross-platform stand-alone executable for teams not comfortable with Java. You don't have to compile code.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `def` with `text` and it will work.

Refer the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#text